# R: creating a portfolio in Google Finance directly from R

Tags: r

Is there a way to create a portfolio A (CSCO,CAT,HPQ) in Google Finance directly from R?

```
require(RGoogleDocs)

auth = getGoogleAuth("abc@def.com", "password",service="finance")
con = getGoogleDocsConnection(auth)

Portfolio A
CSCO
CAT
HPQ
```